# Flutter TextField get Selected Text

Tags: flutter, android-edittext, textfield

In android we can get the starting and ending index of selected text in an EditText using this :

```
int a = inputET.getSelectionStart();
int b = inputET.getSelectionEnd();
```

What is the flutter alternative for this in a TextField ?

Comment: Try to explain what do you want to achieve with this? What would you use it for?

Comment: I am creating an app where i will be manipulating the selected part of the text, i've already done it in the android app,
Lets say a user typed a sentence with 5 words and selected one word and clicked a button, then something would happen to that word, i need the index of the selection for that

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/selection.html)?

Answer (score 8):

It can be a bit more straightforward than Fayaz's answer: with a `TextField(controller: _textEditingController)` one can access the selected text like this:

```
_textEditingController.selection.textInside(_textEditingController.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets say we have this widget in widget tree

```dart
TextField(controller: _textEditingController),
```

on some button press, consider to print the selected text

```dart
printSelectedText(){
   print(_textEditingController.text.substring(_textEditingController.selection.baseOffset,_textEditingController.selection.extentOffset));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Fayaz above is a good solution. However, it will only work when you highlight the text from left to right( the baseOffset will be less than the extentOffset). If you highlight it from right to left, the baseOffSet will now be greater than the extentOffset. This will now cause range-error since the start index in the subString method will be greater than the end index.
I have adjust some line of Fayaz's code to solve this problem

```
int start = textEditingController.selection.baseOffset <
        textEditingController.selection.extentOffset
    ? textEditingController.selection.baseOffset
    : textEditingController.selection.extentOffset;
int end = textEditingController.selection.baseOffset >
        textEditingController.selection.extentOffset
    ? textEditingController.selection.baseOffset
    : textEditingController.selection.extentOffset;
String selectedText = textEditingController.text.substring(start, end);
```